# Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'â€Žâ€Žu1'?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1045

This is extremely basic and I apologize for asking such a rookie question.

But I a getting this error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'â€Žâ€Žu1'@'172.16.3.139' (using password: YES) in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/103503/webspace/httpdocs/eirestudio-tools/crm/add-contact.php on line 53
```

The user says **â€Žâ€Žu1**?

What does this mean?

Here is a sample connection below, note the user, why am I getting **â€Žâ€Žu1**?

```
mysql_connect('localhost', '‎‎user', 'pass');
```

Comment: Are you passing an ANSI string where a UNICODE string is expected?

Comment: Is 172.16.3.19 an authorized IP for that connection? Specifically, is it the IP where the server is?

Comment: What is the username you are passing in? It may help determine what encoding has been applied and that could in turn lead to how it happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why am I getting â€Žâ€Žu1?

Were you expecting just ‘u1’? Where are you reading that string from?

What seems to have happened is that you've got some invisible control characters in your config source somewhere. Specifically, the string ‘â€Ž’ is what you get when you take a Unicode U+200E LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK and encode it into UTF-8, then read it using the Windows-1252 codepage.

This could happen if the username ‘u1’ was being read from a text file: your program might read it as bytes in cp1252 (the default codepage on Western machines), but a text editor would guess it to be UTF-8 and turn those bytes into U+200E characters, which you won't be able to see. I don't know where they originally came from, but you could try re-typing/replacing the source containing ‘u1’ to get rid of them.

Comment: Bingo - It was actually an underscore. I replaced the underscore and voila!

Comment: An underscore? Hmm! I guess it depends on the editor what the character would look like, but normally two LEFT-TO-RIGHT-MARKs would be invisible. Windows-1250 (Central European) is another codepage that would make U+200E to that sequence; the only other possible encoding I can find is ISO-8859-15 and -16, where it would be U+2934 ARROW POINTING RIGHTWARDS THEN CURVING UPWARDS: ⤴⤴